# Why does my ngRoute not do anything?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set up an ngRoute. I don't want to update the view, just perform some changes to the scope when the route is called. I have included angular-route.js and ngRoute.

```
angular.module('todo', ['ngRoute','ngStorage']).
    config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/:state',{
                controller: 'aspectController'
            })
    }).
        controller('aspectController', function($scope){
        console.log('aspect');
    })
```

The expected outcome is that when I visit any page like index.html#/test i would like the console to write "aspect" but nothing happens, i don't get any errors or anything else.

Full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="todo">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Todo.txt</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ngView ng-controller="doController">
        <ul class="aspects">
            <li><a href="#/do">Now</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/deferred">Deferred</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/completed" class="alt">Completed</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <div class="checkboxwrapper">
                <input ng-repeat="task in $store.taskarr track by $index" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <textarea autoexpand class="tasks" ng-change="processTasks()" ng-model="$store.tasks"></textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you add a _default_ route, do you see if fall through?

Comment: I tried otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}); Nothing happened if i visit #/test for example.

Comment: Have you included ng-app="todo" in the html?

Comment: yes. The app is running and I can perform a console.log inside the config-function.

Comment: can you provide your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to update the view

It sounds to me that for this reason you don't use `ngView` directive in your view. In this case you will not be able to to it, since route change will trigger controller only if there is a `ngView` available. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. Also if you don't provide a `template` or `templateUrl` controller will not be triggered too.

Comment: I tried adding ng-view to the body-element, without any result. Is there a better approach to connecting certain url to having certain data populate a scope?

Comment: You also have to provide a `template` for your route. Even `template: ''` is enough.

Comment: I now tried    when('/:state',{
    template: '',
    controller: 'aspectController'
   }) it doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes, you are right, template should not be falsy. `template: 'some'` works. Or just space ` `.

Comment: In html `ngView` becomes `ng-view`. Also you should not put in on body. http://plnkr.co/edit/3vyFDW97mAVw6tPsEznL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some changes in the scope when you change the url what you should do is use a state change event inside your controller:

```
app.controller('doController', function($scope) {
 $scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
    console.log('aspect');
  }

}
```